# Vim Regex to match all commas on line that are not inside brackets

Tags: regex, vim

I think what is needed is a negative lookahead, which would be similar to this in other languages:

`\,(?![^[]*])`

This doesn't work with Vim's regex style and using the `\v` flag doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Matching commas outside brackets by themselves is really hard. It's usually tough when you're matching something without anchors. The right answer typically depends on *what* you're trying to do with that match. Are you splitting fields? Replacing commas with something else? It's usually much easier to match the inverse, the fields in between the commas, including sections in between brackets that may contain commas.

Comment: A negative lookahead is not enough. However, you are using the wrong syntax: Perl's `(?!pattern)` is like Vim's `\(pattern\)\@!`. If you start the regex with `\v` than you can simplify to `(pattern)@!`. Furthermore, not even in Perl `,` is special, so that first `\` is useless.

Comment: can brackets be nested?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if two assumptions are satisfied:

- there are no nested brackets; and
- brackets are balanced.

```
ab,c[de[fg,h]i j]k,m
```

is an example of a string with nested brackets. Given the first assumption the second means that each left bracket is followed by a right bracket with no left brackets in between and each right bracket is preceded by a left bracket with no right brackets in between. This is an example of balanced brackets:

```
ab[cd,ef]g,h[ij]k
```

These are examples of non-nested unbalanced brackets:

```
ab[cd
ab][cd
ab[cd]e]
```

Notice that in the second example the brackets are unbalanced even though the number of left brackets (1) equals the number of right brackets. In third example the final `']'` is preceded by a left bracket but there is a `']'` in between.

These two assumptions allow us to match every comma that is not followed by a right bracket that is not preceded by a left bracket. For that we can use a negative lookahead that contains a character class that matches every character other than a left bracket. With the PCRE (PHP) regex engine that would be:

```
,(?![^[]*])
```

I am reliably informed (see comments) that in Vim that would be:

```
,\([^[]*]\)\@!
```

Negative lookaheads are supported by Vim and most other languages.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nihl5D/2/)

The regex performs the following operations:

```
,         # match ','
(?!       # begin negative lookahead
  [^[]*   # match 0+ characters other than '['
  ]       # match ']'
)         # end negative lookahead
```

It appears that one option is to use another regex engine within Vim. See, for example, this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/196610/can-i-use-perl-regular-expressions-in-the-vim-command-line).

Comment: Your analysis looks good, but your regex syntax is not the correct syntax for Vim. It seems regex101 only supports 4 flavors of regex and none of them actually matches the Vim flavor.  For negative lookaheads on Vim, see [`:help /\@!`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21) in Vim.

Comment: Please convert my PCRE regex to a Vim regex in a comment and I will put it in my answer. btw, I noticed Vim's regex engine is quite powerful, even supporting *variable length* positive and negative lookbehinds.

Comment: This is the Vim equivalent to your regex: `,\([^[]*]\)\@!` Note that the negative lookahead appears at the end, it acts on the preceding token, which is inside a group `\(...\)` so it applies to the whole expression. Note that `[` doesn't require quoting inside `[]` and a literal `]` doesn't require quoting outside of it either. I tested this in Vim and it worked same as your sample test case in regex101. Cheers!

Comment: I only now noticed that my solution is just a tweak of yours. I guess I had only paid attention to the title of your question. I need to be better at reading questions carefully and restraining my desire to get on with finding a solution. I've had that problem for some time. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I will vote for you because of the investment in the answer.

Comment: @TheGridLock, that sounds like [damning with faint praise](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/damn-with-faint-praise), but I'll take it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer has to do with double quoted strings vs single quotes.

`execute "s/,\([^\[]*\]\)\@!/,\r/g"`

The above does not respect the negative lookahead while the following will:

`execute 's/,\([^\[]*\]\)\@!/,\r/g'`

Comment: That's because double quoted strings will process escape sequences with bacsklash, while single quoted strings will not... But in this case it shouldn't matter, because *you don't need to use `execute` here*. Just use the `s/...` command directly. Also see my comment on @CarySwoveland's answer, you don't need backslashes on the `[` and the `]`.

Answer (score 0):

To replace all commas `,` by `-` out the brakets `[]`, you can do this:

> blah, blah, [blah, blah, blah] blah, blah, [blah, blah] , blah,

`:%s/,\|\(\[.\{-}\]\)/-\1/g`

> blah- blah- -[blah, blah, blah] blah- blah- -[blah, blah] - blah-

`:%s/-\[/[/g`

> blah- blah- [blah, blah, blah] blah- blah- [blah, blah] - blah-